# Data structure for storing keys with no associated values

Tags: cocoa, collections, nsdictionary

I need an efficient data structure to hold onto identifiers without the need for a value in the dictionary. Would it work to hold just an `NSNull` as the value for each key or is there a more efficient data structure for fast lookup of keys?

Comment: It's not really clear why you're talking about these objects as "keys" if they're not _keying_ anything. What sort of operations do you need to perform on the pieces of data or on the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `NSSet` or `NSMutableSet`, it is essentially an `NSDictionary` without values.